# PHP: onClick not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, button, onclick

My button "VIEW" is not going to the form of "booking_content.php" instead its just refreshing the page of "home.php"

Here's my code:

```
$radio = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName, MAX(fldTotalDuration) as fldTotalDuration FROM tbldata WHERE fldNetname = '".$get_radio."' AND fldMonth = '".$get_month."' AND fldWeek = '".$get_week. "' GROUP BY fldBldgName ORDER BY id, fldBldgName, fldTotalDuration DESC");

echo "<table class = 'tblMain'>";
echo "<tr align='left'>";
echo "<td><b><u>BUILDING NAME</u></b></td>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($radio))
{   
echo "<tr><td align='left'>";   
echo $row['fldBldgName']."'>";

echo "<input type='image'  src='image/view.png' name='viewBldg' onClick='this.form.action='booking_content.php'; this.form.submit()'>";
echo $row['fldBldgName'];
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

My problem is this one:

```
  echo "<input type='image'  src='image/view.png' name='viewBldg' onClick='this.form.action='booking_content.php'; this.form.submit()'>";
```

*The onClick is not going to the page of booking_content.php instead its just refreshing the page...

I can't upload an example result of my program...

Please click this link so you can view my sample program: http://postimg.org/image/wbiigechn/

ALSO the code for my button is inside of a fieldset...

Comment: Where is the form tag in your code?

Comment: @sємsєм..its in the upper part of my home.php...I didn't include it in the question...but heres the form... <form name='form' method='post' action="">, the code is inside of the form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt will generate the following HTML:

```
<input type='image' src='image/view.png' name='viewBldg' 
onclick='this.form.action='booking_content.php'; this.form.submit()'>
```

So your browser wont be able to interpret the onclick attribute correctly, because the `'` before `booking_content`.
Try the following:

```
echo "<input type='image' src='image/view.png' name='viewBldg' 
onclick=\"this.form.action='booking_content.php'; this.form.submit()\">";
```

Which should generate a valid HTML such as:

```
<input type='image' src='image/view.png' name='viewBldg' 
onclick="this.form.action='booking_content.php'; this.form.submit()">
```

Comment: Can you paste the output generated by PHP? (just the onclick part)

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus...what do you mean about the just onclick part? do u mean the code of booking_content.php??

Comment: I've updated my answer. Whats PHP returing on your HTML page? It should look something like `<input ... onclick='this.form.action="booking_content.php"; this.form.submit()'>`

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus...I tried to put it without using echo and make it html code..its working but when I put it inside of <?php ?> its not working already... I tried your code but still the same, not working.. :(

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus....the code for button is inside of a fieldset...is there anything problem when inserting it in fieldset?

Comment: No, the problem is just a mix of `'` and `"` which leads to malformated HTML. Can you please copy & paste the output source of your PHP script?

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus...I fix it!... thanks for you help... you just forgot to include the "/"...here's my code..echo "<input type='image' src='image/view.png'  name='view'   onClick=\"this.form.action='booking_content.php'; this.form.submit()\"> ";

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus..you can change your answer and i will mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

You tried to access your form in wrong way. `this` in your code refer to the input itself not to the form.

You may have to do something like the following:

```
<input type="button" value="view" onclick="document.fn.action='http://google.com';document.fn.submit();" />
```

where fn the attribute `name` value of your `form`.

**Notice:** in this case you should have only one form with that name.

Check out this demo: http://jsbin.com/asekAqu/1 or its sample code: http://jsbin.com/asekAqu/1/edit

Comment: `this.form` in the event handler of an input inside a form will always reference the surrounding form.